# How to extend a function in dissembled code?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, executable, ida

How can I extend/expand the code of a function in the `IDA` (PRO 7.5 SP3)? I'd like to add some new instructions to the existing function in the disassemble code. I know, that there is a `change function end` option (`hotkey E`) but the problem is that immediately after the function code there is another function code so expanding the function in question i'm just overwriting some existing and potentially important code.

I'm attaching the screenshot of the code in question:

[image]

So am i right that the solution here would be to first "make" some free space in the code just before the function end (moving a bit all the later code, next to the function) and only then add some new instruction by patching. But how to, as I said "make" this free space for the new instructions?

Thx for help.

P.S.

Sorry if the question is a maybe bit lame but i'm a newbie in the topic.

Comment: Find some free space elsewhere in the code and put a jump to it. Often there is some space between functions, which could be enough depending on how much you want to add. Don't try to move all the following code.

Comment: You could just overwrite all the instructions between 401067 and 401071, removing the security  check call, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @prl You rather mean 401071-401076?  Is't  You?

Comment: No.  You can't remove 401076 because it is necessary to restore rsp. 401067 - 40106d are setting up for the call, so they can be removed along with the call. 40106f needs to be retained; it is the return value from main.

Comment: 40107a - 401083 are only called from this one place, so if you remove the call, you have all of that space to play with, too.

Comment: @prl Ok, sorry the 401076 indeed can't be removed. Talking about 401071-401076 i meant omitting the call to that security check procedure. As of the 40107a - 401083 - ok i can utilize that space but this is OLNY 9 bytes long!

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to find some free space elsewhere in the code and put a jump to it.

However, there is a bit of space available here by compacting the existing code and removing the unnecessary security check.

Starting at 401067, overwrite with

```
    401067 xor eax, eax
    401069 leave
    40106a ret
```

That leaves 40106b - 401087 available, which is 29 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This function is so simple, you can rewrite the whole thing to use 26 bytes:

```
401040 push 636261h
401045 mov eax, esp
401047 push 0eh
401049 push eax
40104a push offset _Format
40104f call _printf
401054 xor eax, eax
401056 add esp, 16
401059 ret
```

Then you have 46 bytes available.

Comment: You need `add esp, 16` instead of `leave` since you saved size and instructions earlier by not setting up EBP as a frame pointer.  But yeah, code-golfing a simple function is a good way to open up space, if just stripping out stack-cookie overflow checks like in your other answer isn't sufficient or just for the satisfaction of replacing bloated code. :P